# How to use only 'flask run' command in terminal and add default config variables in code instead?

Tags: python, flask

I would like to start my Flask application with just `flask run` with these config informations: `host = 0.0.0.0`, `port = 443` & `cert = adhoc`. If I wanted to run this through command I would have executed the code below instead:

`flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=443 --cert=adhoc`

But then I have to tell all my group mates and my professor to do it too when they check on my code. So I tried to work around this by using the code below in my app:

```
werkzeug.serving.run_simple("0.0.0.0", 443, app, ssl_context='adhoc')
```

However when I try to close my server with `CTRL+C`, it starts another server that actually would start if I didn't have any config informations. So I was wondering is there any way to go around this? Either it is to continue using werkzeug or to change it to something else.

Here is a shorten version of my code that includes how I have built my app. Tried to include what's just needed. If there's anything I should include more just tell me. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='env',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
    )    

    app.app_context().push()

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass
   
    serving.run_simple("0.0.0.0", 443, app, ssl_context='adhoc')
    return app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables would probably be the correct way to provide these values to the `flask run` command.

You never mentioned your platform, but on Linux, something like:

```
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=9999
```

Causes the dev sever to launch on port `9999` when launched with just `flask run`

You could also put these values in the file `.flaskenv`:

```
FLASK_RUN_PORT=9999
FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

`flask run` should then autoload these values.

By the way [official documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/#builtin-configuration-values) misses these values out, I had to look on [issue 2661](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2661)

Seems `FLASK_RUN_CERT=adhoc` is also a valid one, as per [issue 3105](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/3105).

Not sure if there's an extensive list of these anywhere.

Comment: Hello there! Thank you for your answer. `.flaskenv` worked really well. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.